# Trouble taking auto backup of mysql database to amazon s3

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, mysql, cron

I am new to this concept and i am using ubuntu14.04 lts O.S. I created a bash script which would take backup of mysql db, and also created a cronjob for a desired time. The thing is the backup is going on only for phpmyadmin and sys databases and not my own created database. There is no log maintained by the crontab for that job. Please help me out.

### cronab entry

```
08 4 * * * /bin/sh /usr/bin/s3mysqlbackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

[backup script](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/2206527#file-s3mysqlbackup-sh)

Answer (score 0):

does the script work, if you execute it yourself?
if so - try replacing `/bin/sh` in the crontab with `/bin/bash +x` and replace `/dev/null` with `/tmp/debug-mysqlbackup.log` - this will output all steps to the file `/tmp/debug-mysqlbackup.log`

(still can't create comments ... ;-D)

Comment: Tried! still no luck. Backs up the same thing (phpmyadmin and sys) but not other db's . Help me out here.

Comment: what is in `/tmp/debug-mysqlbackup.log` ?

Comment: No log file created by that name.